# Chrome Extension - Sending event message back to the original tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome-Extension in which `content.js` sends an event to the `bacground.js` which requests a URL from the server. The URL received is sent back to content.js which is browsed **ON THE TAB REQUESTED FROM**. For eg:- If Tab1 has requested, the URL should be browsed on the same tab, not another.

Here's my content and background.js

**Content.js**

```
// sending details to `background.js`.
message = {
    'event_type': 'Event1',
}
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(message);

// listening to `background.js` response.
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(request.event_type === 'Event1Response') {
            window.location.href = request.data.url;
        }
    }
);
```

**Background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        if(request.event_type === 'Event1'){
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
                            message = {  //response from the server
                                'event_type': 'Event1Response',
                                'data': {
                                    'url': some_url
                                }
                            }
                            // Sending response back to the `content.js`.
                            var activeTab = tabs[0];
                            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
);
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": [
            "*://www.example.in/*",
        ],
        "js": ["js/content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }, {
        "matches": [
            "*://www.example2.com/*"
        ],
        "js": ["js/content.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["js/background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        // "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Click here!"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is that the response is returned to the CURRENT active tab, instead of the actual tab where it is requested from. For eg:-

1) Let's say I've 2 tabs T1 and T2.

2) I'm in open state in T1 with `example.in`.

3) Now I open `example2.in` on T2 and quickly switch to T1 tab.

4) T1 will receive the response of server URL U1 and will browse to U1. Instead the response should have been received by T2, which should have browsed  U1.

This is because I'm sending it to the current active tab in my `background.js`.

How can I send the response to the actual tab where the request was initiated? I'm new to Chrome development. how can I rectify this?

Do let me know if I'm not clear in any of the part.

Comment: Simply use sender.tab.id or even simpler: use sendResponse as shown in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple).

Comment: sendResponse didn't work. However, sender.tab.id worked.

Comment: To make sendResponse work you need to change your code (simplify it) as shown in the documentation.